# Facing Marker Issue React using google-map-react

Tags: reactjs, google-map-react

I am trying to achieve a map interface in React. When the user clicks on the map. The marker must get display in that particular coordinates.

```
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";
import marker from "../../Assets/marker.png";
```

```
  const [GmapKey, setGmapKey] = useState("");
  const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState(null);

  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(4);
  const [center, setCenter] = useState({
    lat: 20.5937,
    lng: 78.9629,
  });

  const defaultProps = {
    center: {
      lat: 20.5937,
      lng: 78.9629,
    },
    zoom: 4,
  };

    const [item, setItem] = useState({
    productName: "",
    days: "",
    price: "",
    image: "",
    state: "",
    pincode: "",
    lati: "",
    longi: "",
    city: "",
  });
```

These are the state variables which are being used

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLatlongByPincode = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${item?.pincode}&key=${GmapKey}`
        );
        const { lat, lng } = response.data.results[0]?.geometry?.location;
        setCenter({ ...center, lat, lng });
        setZoom(8);
        setSelectedLocation({ lat, lng });
        setItem({ ...item, lati: lat, longi: lng });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching lat long:", error);
      }
    };
    if (item?.pincode?.length === 6) {
      fetchLatlongByPincode();
    }
  }, [item.pincode, GmapKey]);
```

```
  const handleMapClick = ({ lat, lng }) => {
    setSelectedLocation({ lat, lng });
    setZoom(6)
    setItem({ ...item, lati: lat, longi: lng });
  };
```

These Are the Functions which get triggered on Map Click or When the pincode value will be changed

I am currently trying using

```
        {GmapKey && (
          <div
            className="form-group py-6"
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "400px" }}
          >
            <label htmlFor="location" className={styles.label}>
              Location
            </label>
            <GoogleMapReact
              onClick={handleMapClick}
              bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: GmapKey.toString() }}
              defaultCenter={defaultProps.center}
              defaultZoom={defaultProps.zoom}
              center={center}
              zoom={zoom}
            >
              {/* Marker */}
              {selectedLocation && (
                <div
                style={{ position: "relative" }}
                lat={selectedLocation?.lat}
                lng={selectedLocation?.lng}
                >
                  <img src={marker} alt="mapmarker" className="w-[25px] relative z-50" />
                </div>
              )}
            </GoogleMapReact>
          </div>
        )}
```

My Map Functionality and Zoom functionality is being Triggered also the latitude and longitude are being set by api. Only issue with the marker being displayed

[image]
[image]